# With reflection, is there a reliable way to determine whether a method is visible from a given class?

Tags: java, reflection, visibility

In Java, is there a simple, reliable way to determine whether a method, passed via reflection, is visible from a given class: i.e. the method could be called from the given class without causing an `IllegalAccessException` to be thrown?

I know it's possible to call `setAccessible(true)` on the method to override the Java visibility constraints, but I want to determine whether it's meant to be visible, not call it regardless. The `isAccessible()` method on the `Method` class looked promising, but this just tests whether `setAccessible(true)` has been called.

Simply trying to call the method and then catching the `IllegalAccessException` isn't an option either, because that would only determine the visibility form the current class, not any given class.

So far the only solution I've come up with is to do something like this:

```
public boolean isVisible(Method toBeCalled, Class<?> fromClass) {

    if (Modifier.isPublic(toBeCalled.getDeclaringClass().getModifiers()) && 
            Modifier.isPublic(toBeCalled.getModifiers())) {
        return true;
    }

    if (toBeCalled.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(fromClass) 
            && Modifier.isProtected(toBeCalled.getModifiers())) {
        return true;
    }

    if (fromClass.getPackage().equals(toBeCalled.getDeclaringClass().getPackage()) &&
            ! (Modifier.isPrivate(toBeCalled.getModifiers())) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This works to an extent, but I'm essentially codifying the Java visibility rules, which would require a lot of testing, and I'm sure there are lots of edge cases I've not taken account of around things like inner classes.

Does anyone know of a simple, reliable way to do this?